# Upgrade Ubuntu version with the terminal

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, 64-bit

My PC works with Ubuntu (16.04, 32-bit) and Windows (7, 64-bit) options.

My Ubuntu is broken. The only thing I can do in my user in Ubuntu is to open a terminal.

I want to try to upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10  64 bit using only the terminal.

I seek a step by step instructions that need no prerequisite knowledge.

Comment: There are so many changes if you are having problems with your system I would at least back up your data and try 17.10 from a live usb first. If it runs well I would almost suggest a fresh install.

Comment: @Panther I have no problems with my data because the important data are in Dropbox or Google drive and Evernote. What is a fresh install?

Comment: If you like the way 17.10 looks on a live USB go ahead and install from the usb rather than upgrade from 16.04

Comment: @Panther OK, I didn't found in Google the right link for this. I can download it from Windows 7 or from Ubuntu 16.04 from host user that allows Firefox utilisation. Can you please give me an exact address?

Comment: Download ubuntu - https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: @Panther I don't understand how to load it in USB key. There is a step I surely skipped

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0

Comment: There are complete install guides here and on the ubuntu wiki